# angular animations - pass parameter to trigger from template

Tags: angular, angular-animations

i have a simple animation trigger which fades the element in and out.

```
trigger('fadeInOut', [
  transition(':enter', [
    style({ opacity: 0 }),
    animate('0.1s ease-in-out')
  ]),
  transition(':leave', [animate('0.1s ease-in-out', style({ opacity: 0 }))])
])
```

is there a way I can "configure" this animation from the template on the fly like

```
<div [@fadeInOut]="2"></div>
<div [@fadeInOut]="'0.5s'"></div>
```

The thing I would like to achieve is to pass a set of coordinates, e.g. the offsetX and Y from a mouse click event and animate an element (which is not in the dom yet) to that position.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately there is no way to send parameters into angular animation after component was rendered.

but you can create **trigger function with input value** and send some parameter in to it.

```
const fadeInOut = 
(name, duration) => trigger(name, [
  transition(':enter', [
    style({ opacity: 0 }),
    animate(`${duration}s ease-in-out`)
  ]),
  transition(':leave', [animate(`${duration}s ease-in-out`, style({ opacity: 0 }))])
])
```

Component:

```
@Component({
   ...
  animations: [
    fadeInOut('fadeInOut-1', 0.5),
    fadeInOut('fadeInOut-2', 1)
  ]
})
```

HTML

```
<div [@fadeInOut-1]></div>
<div [@fadeInOut-2]></div>
```

see this example, that i created: 
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-animation-trigger-function

Answer (score 2):

Here is a working solution to provide animation parameter from component template.

Define parameter(s) in your template like this:

```
<div *ngIf="isVisible" [@fadeInOut]="{value: true, params: {myTime: '.4s'}}"></div>
<div *ngIf="isVisible" [@fadeInOut]="{value: true, params: {myTime: '.8s'}}"></div>
<div *ngIf="isVisible" [@fadeInOut]="{value: true, params: {myTime: '1.2s'}}"></div>
```

And then use it inside animation definition:

```
animations: [
  trigger('fadeInOut', [
    transition(':enter', [style({ opacity: 0 }), animate('{{ myTime }} ease-in-out')]),
    transition(':leave', [animate('{{ myTime }} ease-in-out', style({ opacity: 0 }))])
  ])
],
```

Demo there: [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-kqrbxm?file=src%2Fapp%2Fhello.component.ts)